# How to set a specific "Format > Page > Scaling mode" to all my spreadsheets at once?

Tags: printing, libreoffice-calc

I have a document with many spreadsheets and I would like to have them set to a specific "Format > Page > Scaling mode", so that when printing each of them, using a selection of rows, everything can fit a single page.

I know it's possible to do this per spreadsheet as described in the [docs](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Sheet_3#Fit_print_range.28s.29_to_width.2Fheight)

But I would like know if it's possible to set it for the whole document and its all spreadsheets at once.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just modify the page style: Open "styles and formatting" (F11 or Menu View), select page styles, right-click on default page style and set the scaling mode there. Should affect all sheets using that specific page style.

Comment: @tohuwawohu thanks for your reply but, unfortunately, that does not work, I still have to change them individually.